# My application (java) isn't displayed in the window I set for it

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I created a java application in eclipse using processing (processing.org) supposed to be displayed in this window[not displayed at the right place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GGOT.png), but as you can see it's doesn't work.
I already tried the way to compile the app using proclipsing : http://www.instructables.com/id/Proclipsing-Using-the-Eclipse-IDE-for-Processing-p/, but it's doesn't work and I don't want to use this way.
So that's my code :

```
package HelloProcessing;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import processing.core.*;

public class main
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PApplet.main(new String[] {"--present", "HelloProcessing.HelloProcessing"});
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloProcessing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(HelloProcessing.xs, HelloProcessing.ys));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

package HelloProcessing;

import processing.core.*;

public class HelloProcessing extends PApplet
{
    /*
     * public static void main(String args[])
     * {
     * PApplet.main(new String[] {"--present", "HelloProcessing.HelloProcessing"});
     * }
     */

    float rb = 255;
    float gb = 255;
    float bb = 255;
    static int xs = 500;
    static int ys = 500;

    float xe = 150;
    float ye = 150;
    float we = 100;
    float he = 100;

    float re = 255;
    float ge = 0;
    float be = 0;

    float xr = 250;
    float yr = 250;
    float wr = 100;
    float hr = 100;

    float rr = 0;
    float gr = 0;
    float br = 255;

    public void setup()
    {
        background(rb, gb, bb);
    }

    public void settings()
    {
        /* size(500, 500); */
        size(xs, ys);  
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        int ecolor = color(re, ge, be);
        fill(ecolor);
        ellipse(xe, ye, we, he);

        int rcolor = color(rr, gr, br);
        fill(rcolor);
        rect(xr, yr, wr, hr);
    }
}
```

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: No one will download your code. Post the code in question here.

Comment: Please include your code directly in your post as a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, but pastebin is not good for you ?

Comment: OK sorry, I will never do that again.

Comment: Just wait for the code

Comment: DO I have to post it in comments ?

Comment: No, never. Post it as an edit to your question. Please read the [help] files before posting.

Comment: I did it now. Please take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: There's it a way to display the processing into the JFrame or in another thing ? (In fact it's my goal but if I can't)

Comment: Most of us don't do Processing as it is a small corner of Java that (I think) is mainly reserved for certain educational situations.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: But last question : normally in java, what is used to create the window of an application (with code in it).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "normally". I believe that the currently best supported desk-top GUI library would be JavaFX, but the most mature library still would be the older Swing library.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `PApplet.main()` function builds a window for you and displays your Processing sketch in that window.

Then you create a second `JFrame` and display that. But that second `JFrame` doesn't know anything about your Processing sketch. You only ever add an empty `JLabel` to it, so it doesn't have anything to display.

Before Processing 3, you used to be able to embed a `PApplet` directly in a `JFrame`. But after Processing 3, you can no longer do that since `PApplet` doesn't extend `Applet` anymore.

You can still get to the underlying `Component` by going through the `PSurface` class, but that's not exactly friendly to novices. Alternatively, you could use Processing as a Java library and build a `PGraphics` yourself, but that's not exactly trivial either.

Comment: @vrackfall Why exactly do you want to put a Processing sketch in your own JFrame? What goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't know why, but when I'm launching the HelloProcessing like an applet it's doesn't work, but it's working when I launch it like an application, but only in fullscreen as you can see. So I wan't to put it in a "window" (a frame). I already tried all the way to launch it like an applet

Comment: @vrackfall Applets are pretty much dead and shouldn't be used, and `PApplet` can no longer be used as an applet anyway. You can use the `PApplet.main()` or `PApplet.runSketch()` functions to launch your sketch from eclipse. You don't need to build your own `JFrame` for any of that.

Comment: What is the args of PApplet.runSketch()  ?

Comment: @vrackfall Go [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core%2Fsrc%2Fprocessing%2Fcore%2FPApplet.java) and do a search for "runSketch".

Comment: There's it a way to add more args in PApplet.main(new String[] {"--present", "MyProcessingClass"}) ?

Comment: @vrackfall What arguments are you trying to add? You should probably just try something out and post a [mcve] if you don't understand something.

Comment: Just adding an args to set the size of the PApplet when it's launching as an application

Comment: @vrackfall Why do you need that? Just call the `size()` function with whatever size you want.

Comment: Because the application is launched in fullscreen, I don't wan't that.

Comment: @vrackfall Then stop passing in `"--present"` as an argument. That's what's telling it to go full screen.

Comment: @vrackfall You don't close threads on StackOverflow. Generally you upvote and accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Workman say me :
Stop passing in "--present" as an argument. That's what's telling it to go full screen.